# Pretty sure I broke something when I deleted the old partition and resized the current Linux partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I was trying to get rid of the old Windows partition on my computer and just have the Ubuntu 12.04 one. I used GParted to delete the old partition and resize the current Linux. The problem is when I go into devices I see my "OS" hard drive, I right-click to mount it, and it does nothing as if I never clicked it. Please help.

[image]

Comment: post the gparted screenshot.

Comment: http://imgur.com/OClteYa
Screen shot posted

Comment: do you want to delete which partition?

Comment: It looks like you deleted linux, and set the drive for windows. It also seems there is still the windows recovery partition.

Comment: I wanted to delete the windows partition and give the space to the linux to partition since i am gonna run this as my main operating system from now on

Comment: @user268962 I understood that. It's possible (but not likely) that you might recover your linux partition if you remembered the old size.

Comment: It was 200 mb or so

Comment: Unless it was a really important 200 mb, I'd just install ubuntu 14.04 on the entire drive.

Comment: No there wast anything important on there Just the os

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have said in the comments (nothing important on the drive), just do a clean install of your operating system. I'd probably choose 14.04 over 12.04, but both are supported - just select "use entire drive".

Comment: Downloading 14.04 now gonna do what you said be back to post results

Comment: There another issue since the partition was so small whenever i try and download anything it tells me that there is not enough space